# Is it possible to read from protected directory using only PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have a directory containing data that should not be world-accessible until a certain date.

The directory, naturally, should not be directly world-readable with a web browser.  I currently solve this with .htpasswd and .htaccess.

However, there is a world-readable .php file one directory level up.  The PHP file, based on the date, conditionally generates basic HTML tags (e.g., `<img .../>`) that read from the protected directory.

Unfortunately, in my tests, the .php file requires authentication to load the data.  My question is whether I'm trying to do something fundamentally impossible, or whether I can tweak it to make it work.  Also, if it is possible, are there any additional issues (security or otherwise) that I should know about?

Additional information:

- If possible, I would prefer not to use Javascript.
- PHP 5.3 is available.
- Any other ideas for a solution (I already thought of a cron-job, which I might yet do)?

Comment: What kind of data should be protected in this directory? Only html/php or also static files?

Comment: PHP should be able to access these files normally. What kinds specific problems are you having?

Comment: @Truth: just when an unauthenticated user accesses the PHP file, it asks for authentication.  If it is not provided, the PHP file displays, but the data doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing a problem you might have is if you try to output `<img src="protected.jpg" />` even from an unprotected php file, you'll be able to show the HTML but NOT the image file itself.

If i understand correctly what you're trying to do, you need either :

- to write some kind of proxy script in PHP, in order to control access to each file (this is a bit tedious and requires generating the right headers + mime types).
- to control access directly from .htaccess using time/date conditions, which might be your best option. see there : http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html

**Edit : proxy example :** i can't seem to find an example online so this is a function i often use when i wish to control access to a file from PHP (for instance this can be sensitive data whose access needs to be verified from $_SESSION or DB values) :

```
function send_binary_data($path, $mimetype, $filename = null){

    @ob_clean();

    if($filename === null) $filename = basename($path);
    $size = filesize($path);

    //no-cache
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, public');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    //binary file
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        //mimetype
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $filename);
    header('Content-Description: ' . $filename);

    $chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024);
    $buffer = '';
    $handle = fopen($path, 'rb');

    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
        print $buffer;
    }

    $result = fclose($handle);
    unset($handle);
    $handle = null;

    die();

}
```

Of course you still need to restrict direct access from .htaccess but in case of a proxy you'll redirect all requests to your unprotected proxy script, like this :

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proxy.php?file=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

And proxy.php would contain something like :

```
if(!isset($_GET['file'])) die('file not set');
$file = $_GET['file'];

//perform all your custom checking, including security checks due to retrieving data from $_GET, and if access is granted :

$path = 'yourpath/'.$file;
$mimetype = 'defineregardingyour/ownrules';
send_binary_data($path, $mimetype);
```

Comment: "you'll be able to show the HTML but NOT the image file itself"--yes, that's the issue.  Can you clarify what you mean by "proxy script"?  Also, unfortunately, the time date conditions are rather complicated, and change.  I'm not sure using .htaccess is possible.  Thanks,

Comment: I am somewhat confused (because I am a PHP noob), so let me see if I understand what the above does: 1) redirect from my .php file to proxy.php, 2) proxy.php calls send_binary_data, 3) send_binary_data opens the file directly in binary mode and outputs it, emulating receiving data from a .png file?

Comment: Working from that assumption, I was able to write something similar.  Thanks,

Comment: Step 1) is more : redirect all HTTP requests (HTML, images etc.) from private dir to proxy.php. Then proxy.php tries to figure out what was asked initially and "emulates" it yes.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess only serves as an access control directly from the Internet to the directory.

PHP access is controlled by the chmod permissions. Try chmodding it to 755. You can still put password-protection or any other kind of protection on it with the .htaccess-file.

Considering the added comments, I assume you're trying to include images in your output that are inside the protected directory. Naturally, an unauthenticated user cannot access them... Why else would you have protected them?

You can add the files that need to be world-accessible to your .htaccess file.

Comment: better phrasing: php's access is controlled by filesystem-level permissions.

Comment: I tried changing the directory and the files within it to 0755, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: actually, htaccess can do a helluva lot more thancontrol direct access to a directory. like (en/dis)able modules, rewrite rules, set environment variables, php flags, etc. and it controls not just directories but also files and directories within directories.